# Is there a difference between preloading images vs cacheing images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .htaccess

Isn't the purpose of preloading images to cache them so that page is easier to load?

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

## GZIP ##
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
## GZIP ##
```

I was looking into preloading images with javascript but then I realized, wait a minute, I already do that with a few lines in my .htaccess file.  If I have the latter, why would I need the jscript?

Comment: *"...I already do that with a few lines in my .htaccess file..."* Huh? How does your `.htaccess` file tell the client's browser to precache/preload images?

Comment: Edited for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` rules *don't* preload/precache the images. All they do is tell the browser that *if* it loads an image, that's how long it should cache it for.

Preloading images is used to ensure that the image has been downloaded, even the first time, before you go to show it. (At which point, your `.htaccess` rules will tell the browser how long it can keep it around, if it wants to.)

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks for the clarification!  Time to research how to preload images!